# $AR(\infty)$ representation $y_t(1-0.6B+0.08B^2)=\epsilon_t(1-0.5B)$

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, autoregressive

> Let the process $\{y_t\}$ 
>   $$y_t=0.6y_{t-1}-0.08y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t-0.5\epsilon_{t-1}$$ where
>   $\epsilon_t$ is White  Noise with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$.
>   Is possible to find the $AR(\infty)$ representation?

First I write the process using lag operators
$$y_t(1-0.6B+0.08B^2)=\epsilon_t(1-0.5B)$$
If a process have $AR(\infty)$ representation the roots of Moving Average polynomial are $>|1|$.
$$1-0.5B=0\Rightarrow B=2$$
so the process is invertible.

To find the representation I followed some notes that I found

$$\epsilon_t=\frac{(1-0.6B+0.08B^2)}{1-0.5B}=[(1-0.6B+0.08B^2)\sum_{j=0}^\infty (0.5B)^j]x_t$$
$$\epsilon_t=[\sum_{j=0}^\infty 0.5^j B^j-0.6\sum_{j=0}^\infty 0.5^j B^{j+1}+0.08\sum_{j=0}^\infty 0.5^j B^{j+2}]x_t$$
$$\epsilon_t=[1+\sum_{j=0}^\infty (0.5B)^{j+1}-0.6\sum_{j=0}^\infty 0.5^j B^{j+1}+0.08\sum_{j=0}^\infty 0.5^j B^{j+2}]x_t$$
$$\epsilon_t=[1+0.5B-0.6(0.5)B+\sum_{j=0}^\infty 0.5^j B^{j+2}(0.5^2-(0.6)(0.5)+0.08)]x_t$$
$$\epsilon_t=[1+0.5B-0.6(0.5)B-0.02\sum_{j=0}^\infty 0.5^j B^{j+2}]x_t$$
$$\epsilon_t=x_t+0.2x_{t-1}+0.03\sum_{j=2}^\infty 0.5^{j-2}x_{t-j}$$

Is it right?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the line going to $(0.6)(0.5)B$. The term from which I believe you took that term is $0.5^jB^{j+1}$ for $j=0$, and $0.5^0=1$, not 0.5.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Yeah, I think you are right, I will check it again.